# Django serialization get foreign key object with primary key object

Tags: python, django, serialization

I need to serialize a django model instance with foreign keys as another instance. 
for ex.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length='30')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length='30')

class Author(models.Model):
    reg_num = models.CharField(max_length = '30')
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

So in the serialized version of Authon instance, I want something like

```
[
    {
        "fields":
        {
            "reg_num": "CZG29742XD4",
            "person": 
            {
                "fields":
                {
                    "first_name": "Dheerendra",
                    "last_name": "Rathor"
                }
                "model": "person.person",
                "pk": 2
            }
       }
       "model": "person.author",
       "pk": 2
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by providing both `person` and `author` objects to `serializers`.

[image]

[image]

```
In [39]: from person.models import *

In [40]: from django.core import serializers

In [41]: query_obj = Author.objects.get(person__first_name = 'Dheerendra')

In [42]: ser_json = serializers.serialize('json', [query_obj, query_obj.person])

In [43]: ser_json
Out[43]: '[{"pk": 1, "model": "person.author", "fields": {"reg_num": "CZG29742XD4", "person": 1}}, {"pk": 1, "model": "person.person", "fields": {"first_name": "Dheerendra", "last_name": "Rathor"}}]'

In [45]: from ast import literal_eval 

In [46]: ser_json = literal_eval(ser_json)

In [47]: ser_json[0]['fields']["person"] = ser_json[1]

In [48]: [ser_json[0]]
Out[48]: 
[
  {   
        'fields':   
        {
            'reg_num': 'CZG29742XD4',
            'person': 
            {
              'fields': 
                    {
                          'first_name': 'Dheerendra',
                          'last_name': 'Rathor'
                    },
                    'model': 'person.person',
                    'pk': 1
           }
      }
  'model': 'person.author',
  'pk': 1
  }
]
```

You can convert it back to `json` object using `simplejson` library.

```
In [1]: import simplejson

In [2]: ser_json = simplejson.dumps([ser_json[0]])
```

Comment: @Dheerendra Please review my answer so that if its not upto your need i would like to imrpove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use python module json

[Json documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Write a function that returns the required json.

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't support this in-depth serialization

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4656

You can use [django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) or [tastypie](http://tastypieapi.org/) to do that. Both are well capable to do that.